# generating TableOfContents using Word VBA, siimple VBA method not working properly

Tags: vba, ms-word

I don't understand Why t he following function returning "Nothing"

```
Public Function generatsTOC(ByRef doc As Word.Document) As Word.TableOfContents

    Dim toc As Word.TableOfContents

    Set toc = doc.TablesOfContents.Add(range:=doc.range(0, 0), UseHyperlinks:=True, _  
              UseFields:=False, UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
              UpperHeadingLevel:=1, LowerHeadingLevel:=4, IncludePageNumbers:=True, _ 
              RightAlignPageNumbers:=True)

    Set generatesTOC = toc

End Function
```

In the next class...

```
dim itoc as word.TableOfContents
dim tcg as TableOfContentsGenerator
set tcg = new TableOfContentsGenerator

Set itoc = tcg.generatsTOC(doc)
```

When I am watching itoc, it is `NOTHING`.

I don't see to figure out how is it not working?

Comment: It was the sillyest mistake on planet .

I resolved the problem by 
correcting the SPELLING of : generatsTOC  >>>> generatesTOC

Comment: That's what Option Explicit is for. ;-)

Comment: @ tim, right. Thank y ou. may be I missed to write that. I will be carefull now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the silliest mistake on planet . I resolved the problem by correcting the SPELLING of : generatsTOC >>>> generatesTOC